# find value and write it in 12,2 chars long format

Tags: linux, awk, scripting

example input:

```
:20:210301/9944072
:25:PL63213000342008099410720012
:28C:6032563
:60F:C2101010101PLN4138,23
:61:2101010101D13,61
:86:^101
^20Text ANY
^27YTRDTAL co. ltd.
^30
^31
```

find lines that start with one of these:
:60F: :61: :62M: :60M: :62F:

find value that starts after string C, or D, or PLN (value in example is 4138,23 and 13,61)

write value in format of 12,2 characters

needed output:

```
:20:210301/9944072
:25:PL63213000342008099410720012
:28C:6032563
:60F:C2101010101PLN000000004138,23
:61:2101010101D000000000013,61
:86:^101
^20Text ANY
^27YTRDTAL co. ltd.
^30
^31
```

**EDIT:**
before I've used awk to change date format from YYMMDD to YYMMDDMM like this:

```
cat ./${file}.tmp.mt940 | awk -F ':61:' '{if ($1)
print $1;
else
printf "%s%s%s%s\n", substr($0,0,6), substr($0,7,4), substr($0,7,4), substr($0,11,40)
}' > ${file}.tmp2.mt940
```

now I try to do same with adding zeros but do not now how to search in awk between two different chars/strings (D,C,PLN and comma)

**EDIT: final working solution:**

```
cat ./${file}.tmp2.mt940 | gawk -F '/^:60F:/ or
/^:60M:/ or
/^:61:/ or
/^:62F:/ or
/^:62M:/' '{if (match($0, /^(.*)(PLN|C|D)([0-9]+),([0-9]+)$/, p)) {
    printf("%s%s%012d,%02d\n", p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4]);
  } else
print $1
}' > ${file}.mt940
```

Comment: Welcome, please edit your question and include what you already tried on your own, so we don't suggest the same things. Also, it seems that input and output are identical.

Comment: @Panki Not really identical, but the differences needs to be pointed out. See the two lines ending in `23` and `61`.

Comment: If a line ends with `,1`, should that be changed to `10` or to `01`, or not at all?  You only have example with two digits (`,23` and `,61`).

Comment: it's MT940 export of banks operations.

Comment: In line :61: there is YYMMDDMM letter D and value of operation. I need this value with zeros in front to have 12,2 digits

Comment: Is this homework? If so, what have you yourself tried?

Comment: You keep saying "12,2", but what if the value at the end of the `:61:` line said `13,6`,  what should it be then, `000000000013,60` or `000000000013,06` or `000000000013,6`?

Comment: there will not be one digit after comma. there will be two: 13,60 > 000000000013,60 or 13,06 > 000000000013,06

Comment: (1) It sounds like you are guaranteeing that there will always be exactly two digits after the comma. If that's the case, why not just say "take the number that appears after the `C`, `D` or `PLN` and before a comma and write it as a 12-digit number (with leading zeroes)"? Why talk about `,2` if all the values already have two digits? (2) Your data are confusing: On line 4 (the line with `:60F:`), there's a value after `C` (`2101010101`) and then ***also*** the ``4138,23`` after the `PLN`.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …   So, what is the rule? Will the desired value always be at the end of the line? (If so, the matter of line endings becomes critical.) (3) What if the value after the `C`, `D` or `PLN` is already more than 12 digits (e.g., `D123456789012345.17`?) Can it ever begin with a `-` (minus sign)?

Comment: good questions :) but solution gave @mkayaalp. Those are bank operations i polish zloty (PLN) I would be happy to have operation bigger ther 12 digits ;) thanks

Comment: The "final working solution" should be posted as an answer and *not* in the question itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**final working solution:**

```
cat ./${file}.tmp2.mt940 | gawk -F '/^:60F:/ or
/^:60M:/ or
/^:61:/ or
/^:62F:/ or
/^:62M:/' '{if (match($0, /^(.*)(PLN|C|D)([0-9]+),([0-9]+)$/, p)) {
    printf("%s%s%012d,%02d\n", p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4]);
  } else
print $1
}' > ${file}.mt940
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit *awk*ward in POSIX `awk`:

```c
/^:60F:/ ||
/^:60M:/ ||
/^:61:/ ||
/^:62F:/ ||
/^:62M:/ {
  n1 = match($0, /(PLN|C|D)[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/);
  if (n1) {
    p1 = substr($0, 0, n1-1);
    r1 = substr($0, n1);
    n2 = match(r1, /[0-9]/);
    p2 = substr(r1, 0, n2-1);
    r2 = substr(r1, n2);
    n3 = index(r2, ",");
    p3 = substr(r2, 0, n3-1);
    p4 = substr(r2, n3+1);
    printf("%s%s%012d,%02d\n", p1, p2, p3, p4);
    next;
  }
}
1
```

If you can use `gawk`, it is much better:

```c
/^:60F:/ ||
/^:60M:/ ||
/^:61:/ ||
/^:62F:/ ||
/^:62M:/ {
  if (match($0, /^(.*)(PLN|C|D)([0-9]+),([0-9]+)$/, p)) {
    printf("%s%s%012d,%02d\n", p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4]);
    next;
  }
}
1
```

Comment: gawk: :60F:C210301PLN000000000000,4538

Comment: awk works ok: :60F:C210301PLN000000004538,13

Comment: my problem was dos end of line (^M) and if-loop. when i try to use if then your solution do not work, i'm not sure why yet

Comment: Fixed it, there was one extra set of parenthesis.